# how to get process id from process name in linux programatically

Tags: linux, ace

In my project, we use the ACE ( Adaptive Communication Environment) middleware to write OS independent code that would run on both Windows and Linux.

The requirement is to the get the process id from process name. 
Since ACE does not support this, we will have to use platform specific macros to separate the code for windows and linux.

For windows I would have to use either of - EnumProcesses or CreateToolhelp32Snapshot

How to do the same on linux using an API ?

Programming language is C++

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, you can do this from c++

```
char buf[512];
FILE *cmd_pipe = popen("pidof -s process_name", "r");

fgets(buf, 512, cmd_pipe);
pid_t pid = strtoul(buf, NULL, 10);

pclose( cmd_pipe );
```

here is an another example: [Get process id by name in Linux using C++](http://proswdev.blogspot.de/2012/02/get-process-id-by-name-in-linux-using-c.html)

Comment: Looks good. But even here we use the 'pidof' command. Is there no API interface similar to Windows?

Comment: i'm not sure, if existing an API. Boost lib maybe. In the standart lib existing  a function, which returns the process id of the application.  getpid() returns the process ID of the calling process  OR  getppid() returns the process ID of the parent of the calling process. source: http://linux.die.net/man/2/getpid